# Can't browse to local IIS site with local user

Tags: iis, ftp, filezilla

I'm trying to setup a very basic FTP site on my local machine using IIS and then to browse to it.
And although it seems simple, I just can't get it to work with basic authentication.

The risk posting it here is that the answer seems simple as the error I'm getting is

```
Response:   530-User cannot log in.
Response:    Win32 error:   The user name or password is incorrect. 
Response:    Error details: Anonymous authentication is not allowed.
Response:   530 End
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

So the typical response will be that my password is wrong. But I've tried many options including copy and paste of the password to make sure it's the same. Same error.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Here are my config settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: changing the encryption to use Plain FTP (insecure) does not make a difference.

[image]

Comment: What other logon methods have been confirmed for this account (console, network ,etc).

Comment: None really. Just created the account as a test for the FTP connection.

Comment: First thing to check is logon the account using some other method. Console logon and network logon.